# ¿Como hago para checar si una respuesta en json viene vacio desde un webservice .svc?

Tags: c#, ajax, .net

hago un post desde un formulario y cuando retorna el json con los objetos de una tabla sql me los da sin problemas.. pero cuando no hay datos en la tabla y regresa vacio el json me lo regresa  mal formado ejemplo quiero controlarlo para que no me salgan errores como en la imagen

[image: este es el error que me ocaciona]

{"data:]"}  <- respuesta con json vacio y mal formado *falta un [ *

{"data:["algo","algo","algo"]"} <--- uno con datos me lo da bien

la peticion la hago de la siguiente manera

```
    [OperationContract]
    //[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public Stream buscaPedim(string usuario, string estado, string buscarPor, string fecha_ini, string fecha_fin)
    {


        getPedimentos Pedimentos = new getPedimentos();
        string res = Pedimentos.consulta(usuario, estado, buscarPor, fecha_ini, fecha_fin);

        if (res != null)

            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType =
   "application/json; charset=utf-8";



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hice una actualizacion hoy

```
    public Stream buscaPedim(string usuario, string estado, string buscarPor, string fecha_ini, string fecha_fin)
    {


        getPedimentos Pedimentos = new getPedimentos();
        string res = Pedimentos.consulta(usuario, estado, buscarPor, fecha_ini, fecha_fin);

        if (res != null)

            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType =
   "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        if (res == "")
        {
            //que puedo hacer aqui con el json vacio?
        }
        else 
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(res));
    }
```